# GORM createCriteria and the result set do not return the same results

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-3.3.x

In the createCriteria using max:50 and offset:0, I have a projection like below

```
projections {
sum('downloads')
sum('clicks')
groupProperty('site')
groupProperty('link')
groupProperty('device')
}
```

totalCount returns 939 rows and the result set returns 8. How I can get the no of resultset? I tried resultSet.size but doesn't help because it returns max 50. Right now, I'm running two queries to get the number of records. But is there any way that I can get the resultset with total number in one shot?

Comment: I don't know if it's the best approach but what do you think about to add one count(*) or count('site') and then get the amount directly from the DB?

Comment: I tried but didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: What do you think to hit the db twice, once asking the count and another to get data? Solve your problem and keep thinking a way to do it better. :-)

Comment: Thanks, @PedroHenrique. That's what I'm doing right now. Once for counting and one more time to get the data. But need help for a better way as I'm new in Grails.